# Dynamic , static headers in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I made the navigation bar static which used simple css and html code. I want to know how this can be made dynamic, while scrolling down, or up. What can I change, or add to this code to make that happen?  If not this block of code, then any other way is also appreciated.

```
     <header class="site-header">
     .site-header{
     background: #1dafec;
     height: 52px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 10;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     z-index: 999;
     }
```

Comment: Dynamic in what way? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want the header to be as it is, and when I scroll down, the header is supposed to narrow down and stay fixed.

Comment: That doesn't really explain matters, "narrow down"...to what, when etc. You really need to make a demo. You're going to need javascript if you want things to happen when scrolling.